# How do I have one page in portrait and the rest in landscape in Google Docs?

Tags: google-docs, formatting

I am working on a school project and I need one page in portrait and the rest in the landscape. I would rather not have multiple documents though. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this is not possible. You can either have Portrait mode or Landscape mode. Combination of both modes in one document is unlikely. (you may try to create such desired document in desktop MS Office Word 2016+ and then drop it into Google Drive and convert it into Google Docs, or maybe you will get lucky with OneDrive and MS Online Word instead)

[image: 0]